# Loading html with ajax instead of hardcoding breaks easy-tree plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using this nice plugin to generate a tree in my webpage:

https://github.com/zgs225/easy-tree

When hardcoding the listitems into the html of the page, I get a perfect result. All styling etc.. works.

However when retrieving the listitems with ajax (html string) the tree is not styled correctly. I assume this has something to do with the order in which everything is loaded and styled. Any ideas where this has gone wrong?

```
 $.ajax({ 
        url: "@(Url.Action("YearTree", "Year"))", 
        data: {year: yearid},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length != 0) {
                $(".easy-tree").append(data);
                $(".easy-tree").EasyTree({
                    selectable: true,
                    deletable: false,
                    editable: false,
                    addable: false,
                    i18n: {
                    }
                });
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Output of the ajax:

```
"<ul><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li><li>Example 3<ul><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li></ul></ul>"
```

Controller:

```
string a = "<ul><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li><li>Example 3<ul><li>Example 1</li><li>Example 2</li></ul></ul>"; 
return Json(new string[] { a }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

---

I've made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pbxhtj3b/

Comment: try `$('.easy-tree').html(data)` instead of `append(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the outer quotes of the html string shown are really being sent you should just remove them at server and send the html string alone. Then change `dataType` accordingly ( or remove it)

The order of your code is correct however those extra quotes are causing invalid html to be inserted in the DOM

If the target element is emty you can use your append...if you want to replace existing html in that element use `html()` method

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. I've added a fiddle.

Comment: works fine here loading tree with ajax  http://plnkr.co/edit/CxTxwhVD7oOSKZsl6Krd?p=preview